# Error- Connection String property has not been initialized (C# Database)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

**Error:**

> The error says:- The ConnectionString Property has not been
>   initialized at system.data.OledbOledConnection.PermissionDemand().

I am unable to figure out the error. Can someone explain what does it mean and how to solve it?

**C# Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;//microsoft database
namespace AccessLoginApp
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\admin\Documents\Book Database.accdb;
        Persist Security Info=False;";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error"+ ex);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try{
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = " Insert into Book Name(Book Name,Book Number,Publisher) values('" + bookName.Text + "','" + bookNumber.Text + "','" + publisher.Text + "')";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }

    }




}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `connection` in the form load and the `button1_Click` event are different instance of the class `OleDbConnection`(obviously they are different) and you have not initialized the connection variable with connection string in the `button1_Click` event(It causing the error as well). If you do that means your code will works **just fine**, If you replace the concatenated queries with `Parameterized` queries means your code will **works great**. And the introduction of `using` statements will makes your code **perfect**. You can try the following:

```
string conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\admin\Documents\Book Database.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
// This will be the connection string
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Need not to do anything regarding connection
    // some other statements if needed
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conString)) // Create and initialize connection object
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = " Insert into Book(Book_Name,Book_Number,Publisher) values(@BookName,@BookNumber,@Publisher)";
                command.Parameters.Add("@BookName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = bookName.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@BookNumber", OleDbType.Integer).Value = bookNumber.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Publisher", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = publisher.Text;                     
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
      MessageBox.Show("Data Saved");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Identifier expected, int is a keyword. How to use it?

Comment: @YoMama: change it as `Integer`

Comment: Thanks for the help but, It is still giving me error..Error.System.Data.OledbException(0x80040e14):Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: most probably the empty spaces in the table name as well as in the column names may create issues, replace those spaces with Underscode in database as well as in code or else enclose them within a pair of `[` and `]` in the query to avoid the syntax errors

Comment: I didn't understand, which empty space are you referring to? and where to add [ ], can you please demonstrate that in your code.

Comment: See the column name `Book Name` their is a space in between `Book` and  `Name` you have to replace those space with `_` in the table definition as well as in the query, or else use like this : `Insert into Book([Book Name], .......)`

Comment: Actually, the name of the table itself is Book Name. And Book Name, publisher and Book Number are the columns, present in it.